# CSS - centralising UL for responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsiveness

I am doing some responsive design, and want a UL to centralise when browser is less than 479px. Here is what I thought would work, but it isn't...

```
@media (max-width: 479px) {
#services {
    background-color: #063;
    margin-top: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#services ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#services ul li {
    margin: 0 12px 12px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
}
```

This is the CSS for the standard desktop view:

```
#services {
height: 128px;
margin-top: 12px;
}

#services ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

#services ul li {
float: left;
margin: 0 12px 0 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="services">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="/assets/images/cleaning.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="/assets/images/cleaning2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="/assets/images/cleaning3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

If anyone can spot what I have done wrong here I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you,

Paul

Comment: whats the html structure for this?

Comment: are you aligning #services or #services ul? or are you just trying to center the text within the list?

Comment: You'll need to include more information. Your HTML, and other CSS that is being applied.

Comment: Check out this site for [centering in css](http://howtocenterincss.com/)

Comment: Hi Aaron, I have updated with all CSS & HTML. I am using images within the UL. Want the whole UL itself to jump centralised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here, in your standard desktop css:

```
#services ul li {
 float: left;  //THIS IS THE PROBLEM
 margin: 0 12px 0 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

Provide, display: inline instead of float: left.
like this,

```
#services ul li {
  display: inline; //SOLUTION
  margin: 0 12px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do so you can remove the

's float:

```
#services ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 12px 0 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

This can go for the desktop version as well or just do it in the media query then in the media query add margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto to the ul:

```
#services ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Sample: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdWLxb